# Getting Site cant be reached on random pages in Chrome and Edge but not in firefox

Tags: google-chrome

I have a large web application. Since 2 weeks, it has started showing a "Site Cant be reached" error on random pages. The error comes for a second and then the page auto refreshes and data gets loaded.
I did an analysis using the netlog tool and found this in the net log viewer. Its showing a net_error -100 and a net_error -383. Any idea what is causing this ?

```html
t=31983 [st=   2]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_RESTART_AFTER_ERROR
                         --> net_error = -100 (ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED)
t=31983 [st=   2]       +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=1086]
t=31983 [st=   2]          HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_BOUND
                           --> source_dependency = 25583 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER)
t=33069 [st=1088]          HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                           --> source_dependency = 25584 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=33069 [st=1088]       -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=33069 [st=1088]       +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE_CONNECTED  [dt=0]
t=33069 [st=1088]          PRIVATE_NETWORK_ACCESS_CHECK
                           --> client_address_space = "unknown"
                           --> resource_address_space = "public"
                           --> result = "blocked-by-inconsistent-ip-address-space"
t=33069 [st=1088]       -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE_CONNECTED
                         --> net_error = -383 (ERR_INCONSISTENT_IP_ADDRESS_SPACE)
t=33069 [st=1088]     -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                       --> net_error = -383 (ERR_INCONSISTENT_IP_ADDRESS_SPACE)
t=33069 [st=1088]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE_RESPONSE_STARTED  [dt=0]
t=33069 [st=1088] -CORS_REQUEST
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting the solution here which solved the issue.
I think the possible issue was because my servers where in North America and users were in Asia. I switched to another server provider in asia and it solved the issue.